# MySQL query is showing no results SELECT * FROM user u JOIN cart c ON u.userid=c.userid JOIN product_cart p ON p.productid=c.cid;

Tags: mysql

why is my MySQL query showing no results, ERD diagram is shown
There is users with a cart and carts that have productID.

Diagram link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgcP3.png

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
JOIN cart c ON u.userid=c.userid
JOIN product_cart p ON p.productid=c.cid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your diagram, you should rather join `product_cart` and `cart` on `cartID` and not on `productID`:

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
JOIN cart c ON u.userid=c.userid
JOIN product_cart pc ON pc.cartid=c.cartid;
```